# Is there any better way to convert Array<int> to Array<String> in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

A **very huge** DataFrame with schema:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ext: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
```

So far I try to `explode` data, then `collect_list`:

```
select
  id,
  collect_list(cast(item as string))
from default.dual
lateral view explode(ext) t as item
group by
  id
```

But this way is too expansive.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can simply cast the `ext` column to a string array

```
df = source.withColumn("ext", source.ext.cast("array<string>"))
df.printSchema()
df.show()
```